# Apache POI Formula Evaluation Slow

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel Spreadsheet with 11 sheets. I'm only using one sheet though and it has 500 rows. I'm basically just converting that sheet into a csv file but using a pipe | instead of a comma and doing some other things like erasing the column header names and adding a UUID to each row. Most of the columns are formulas and when I add in the formula evaluation lines it makes the program take about 5 minutes to process. How can I speed up the formula evaluation and am I doing something wrong with it?

```
    private static void parse(String inputFile, String outputFile) {

    System.out.println("Started Program");

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String formattedTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(timeStamp);

    String file = "";

    try {

        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFile));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        Sheet sheetFinal = workbook.getSheet("Final");
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheetFinal.iterator();

        // Skip the column row
        if(iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
        }

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

            UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

            file += uuid + PIPE + formattedTimeStamp + PIPE + inputFile;

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {

                    evaluator.evaluateInCell(currentCell);
                }

                //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
                //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {

                    file += PIPE + currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {

                    file += PIPE + currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                } else if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BOOLEAN) {

                    file += PIPE + currentCell.getBooleanCellValue();
                }
            }

            file += "\n";
        }

        File newFile = new File(outputFile);

        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newFile, file);

        newFile.createNewFile();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Comment: Performance issues with `apache poi` are mostly not solvable without having the parsed file. But what I woud trying first is using [FormulaEvaluator.evaluate(Cell cell)](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#Using+FormulaEvaluator.) and further proceding with the resulting `CellValue` instead of using `evaluateInCell` since `evaluateInCell` will rewriting the cell but `evaluate` will not.

Comment: I am so disappointed when seeing this comment from you  @Axel Richter, it means it would be very hard to improve it. Compared with another excel API, it's almost 10 times slower.

Answer (score 3):

you can let excel do the work if the user opens the excel-file.

```
 workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```